# Django Rest Framework: How to include application namespace when defining HyperlinkedRelatedField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My django application has a namespace defined in the `app_name` variable, in `urls.py`.

It seems like this namespace needs to be specified in the `view_name` argument of `HyperlinkedRelatedField` for `HyperlinkedRelatedField` to successfuly retrieve the relevant url router.

To avoid repeating this namespace, I'd like to import the namespace into the serializers module. However I get an import error when doing so.

extract from my app/urls.py:

```py
...
app_name = 'viewer'
...

api_router = DefaultRouter()

api_router.register('year', api_views.YearViewSet, 'api_year')
api_router.register('month', api_views.MonthViewSet, 'api_month')
...

urlpatterns = [
...
    path('api/', include(api_router.urls)),
]
```

api_views.py

```py
...
class YearViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Year.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    serializer_class = YearSummarySerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = YearDetailSerializer(instance=instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @action(detail=True)
    def months(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = YearMonthsSerializer(instance=self.get_object(), context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
...
```

serializers.py

```py
...
from .urls import app_name

...

class YearMonthsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    month_set = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name=  app_name + ':api_month-detail',
        lookup_field='slug'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Year
        fields = ['month_set']
...
```

When I manually enter the app_name ('viewer') the serializer works as intended, however when I try to import `app_name` from `.urls`, python throws an ImportError

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'app_name' from 'cbg_weather_viewer.viewer.urls'
```

I don't understand why I get this import error as I already use relative imports models, views, etc. successfully.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. What should I do instead?

**Edit**

I understand that I cannot include url as it will create a circular reference.
After doing some research, it seems that the request contains the app_name value as documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch

However, I don't know how to access the request directly in the `YearMonthSerializer` class. I could retrieve it using `self.request` in a class method, but not directly from the class itself. Any suggestion?

**Temporary solution**

I have deported the app namespace to the apps.py module and imported it both urls.py and serializers.py as follow:

apps.py

```
app_namespace = 'viewer'  # Used in urls
```

urls.py

```
from .apps import app_namespace

app_name = app_namespace
```

serializers.py

```
from .apps import app_namespace

def get_view_name(view_name):
    return f'{app_namespace}:{view_name}'
...

    month_set = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name=  get_view_name('api_month-detail'),
        lookup_field='slug'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

put namespace in the path when you include URLs like this 
without namespace don't retrieve app_name 
try this

```
urlpatterns = [
...
    path('api/', include(api_router.urls,namespace="viewer")),
]
```

Comment: It doesn't work, as it throws the following error:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.`

Comment: I tried to change my pattern as follow `path('api/', include((api_router.urls, app_name) , namespace=app_name))`, but that doesn't seem to resolve my issue: the namespace is still required when specifying the view name, as shown in the stacktrace: `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'api_month-detail' not found. 'api_month-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of the restframework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) states following, which worked for me:

> You may use include with an application namespace:
>
> ```
> urlpatterns = [
>     path('forgot-password/', ForgotPasswordFormView.as_view()),
>     path('api/', include((router.urls, 'app_name'))),
> ]
> ```
>
> Or both an application and instance namespace:
>
> ```
> urlpatterns = [
>     path('forgot-password/', ForgotPasswordFormView.as_view()),
>     path('api/', include((router.urls, 'app_name'), namespace='instance_name')),
> ]
> ```
>
> See Django's URL namespaces docs and the include API reference for
> more details.

Pay attention to the double parenthese with the include statement in the first example:

```
include((router.urls, 'app_name'))
```